# Objective C - Cannot initialize return object of type 'id'

Tags: objective-c, enums

I used the code of my friend in my project but I'm getting this error (his code has no error in his project.)

Error:`Cannot initialize return object of type 'id'with an rvalue of type 'AsyncTaskResult_e'`

The error occurs on .m file (return Fail;)

Here is the .h file

```
#ifndef AsyncTask_h
#define AsyncTask_h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef enum AsyncTaskResult_e {
    Success,
    Fail
}

AsyncTaskResult_t;

@protocol AsyncTaskInterface

@required
-(void)preExecute:(id)parameters;
-(id)doInBackground:(id)parameters;
-(void)postExecute:(id)result;

@end

// This interface is imitated AsyncTask of Android
@interface AsyncTask : NSObject<AsyncTaskInterface>

-(void) executeParameters:(id)parameters;

@end

#endif /* AsyncTask_h */
```

Here is the .m file

```
#import "AsyncTask.h"

@implementation AsyncTask

-(void) executeParameters:(id)parameters {
    [self preExecute:parameters];
    __block id result;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        result = [self doInBackground:parameters];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self postExecute:result];
        });
    });
}

-(void)preExecute:(id)parameters {
    // Run on main thread (UIThread)
}

-(id)doInBackground:(id)parameters {
    // Run on async thread (Background)
    return Fail;
}

-(void)postExecute:(id)result {
    // Run on main thread (UIThread)
}

@end
```

Am I missing something to implement this code?

Comment: `Fail` is an enum, the function that is returning it returns `id` which is an object. An enum can't be cast into an object.

Comment: Why with the down votes? Is it wrong to ask a question you don't know?

Comment: @user3423040 There is no reason why your question has any down votes and no reason for the close votes. Your question shows the relevant code, it asks a clear question, and it explains what error you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really just what it says on the tin. The function doInBackground returns an id, but the type of AsyncTaskResult_e is an int. Because integers are value types, they can't be stored inside of an id (which is a generic objective C object) without being first boxed by turning them into an NSNumber. You could do this by using the [@()](http://nshipster.com/at-compiler-directives/#object-literals) operator, but unless you're actually wanting to return an object here you'd probably be better off changing the return type of the function to AsyncTaskResult_e.

To explain the error a bit better, an rvalue is generally just the thing on the right side of any assignment expression. [This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f90831hc.aspx) goes into more detail.